# CMultiReportTemplate assert

Tags: visual-c++, unicode, mfc, internationalization, mdi

Sorry about the short title, but I honestly can't get a better description of what is happening because I don't know enough...

Some background first, I am "converting" a multi-byte application to support unicode and I've made the standard char/string wchar_t/wstring changes and the my code is building without problems.

What happens is that when the application is being initialized it hits an assert when it registers the applications's document templates. The code is the standard

```
CMultiDocTemplate* pRepDocTemplate = NULL;
pRepDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(IDR_DIAGNOSTIC_REPORT_TYPE,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CDiagnosticReportDoc),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
        RUNTIME_CLASS(CDiagnosticReportView));
```

and CDiagnosticsReportView has the standard DECLARE_DYNCREATE and IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE in the header and source.

The assert is at doctmpl.cpp line 29 (mfc120ud.dll - at least is using the correct dll), but I can't find the source code anywhere to actually know what is happening.

The inheritance tree is pretty straightforward:

```
CDiagnosticReportView 
\->CReportViewBase 
   \->CXTPReportView 
      \->CView
```

CXTPReportView is part of a framework that we are using which is provided by Codejock (Codejock extreme toolkitPro). From the build pane I know that it's linking against it's unicode debug dll (ToolkitPro1631vc120UD.dll)

Suffice to say that in the multibyte configuration this problem doesn't occur.

The project is configured to use the UNICODE character set (Project properties->Configuration Properties->General->Character Set).

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all had to do with the fact that I was linking against the non UNICODE build of Codejock. Even though I saw a reference to the UNICODE dll, the lib wasn't the correct one!

Problem was solved when I opened my eyes ;)